# Database - phpmyadmin

Tags: database, phpmyadmin

I would like to know does database is erased on daily basis which is created PHPMyadmin

Yesterday I have created a database by clicking "new" option under the Server "phpmyadmin demo-MYSQL(root)".Today that database doesn't exist.Any suggestions please and let me know whether I have missed nay steps before creating a database

Comment: No database do not deleted automatically, maybe it wasn't saved/.

Comment: But I have created and worked on it yesterday..Is any save option is there

Comment: Yes at bottom right there is button of `SAVE` or `GO`

Comment: Go option is for execute the query...I couldn't find any save option

Comment: create table, set its structure and then save.

Comment: ok..You mean using "get auto-save query"  option we can save it right?

Answer (score 1):

You were using a demo.phpmyadmin.net server which is not intended for production and which removes databases created by testers on a daily basis.